# Excel - Match rows in another file

Tags: microsoft-excel

A questão é:
The question is:

Tenho2 ficheiros csv, um deles tem apenas uma coluna "email" com várias linhas de emails válidos, tenho também outro ficheiro que tem os mesmo emails e mais alguns, neste ficheiro existem outras colunas como, País, Cidade, Nome etc..

O meu objetivo é filtrar o segundo ficheiro todas linhas em que email esteja presente o ficheiro de emails válidos + invalidos + info (país, cidade, etx..)
Tipo isto:

Ficheiro de e-mails válidos:

```
email            |
------------------
example@gmail.com
------------------
```

Ficheiro de e-mails válidos + inválidos + info:

```
email | name | city | country
------------------------------
example@gmail.com | Miguel | Porto | PT
------------------------------------------
invalid@gmail.com | Invalid | Lisbon | PT
```

O resultado deveria ser todos os e-mails válidos + info:

```
email | name | city | country
------------------------------
example@gmail.com | Miguel | Porto | PT
------------------------------------------
```

Os ficheiros contêm milhares de linhas, não exequível apagar linha a linha. Como posso fazer isto?
Obrigado!

Comment: Olá, este é o Stackoverflow **em português**, então apreciaríamos se você pudesse traduzir a sua pergunta para o português (ou, alternativamente, postá-la no [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/)). Obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Olá, você tem que fazer isso através do VBA ou quer fazer para o trabalho e pode ser por fórmulas?

se puder ser feito por fórmulas a solução é um tanto simples. Bastaria fazer um index-match ou um simples Vlookup(procv) com um if para o segundo ficheiro.

Desta forma, a solução poderia ser colocar esta fórmula abaixo no segundo ficheiro, em uma coluna depois de "country" como nome que quiseres (Valid e-mails/ pro exemplo):

```
=if(vlookup("célula onde está o e-mail";"no ficheiro 1 Coluna inteira onde está o e-mail";1;0)="célula onde está o e-mail";"Válido"-entre aspas mesmo;"Não Válido"-também entre aspas)
```

Se continuar com problemas é só me avisar.